# Error using Boto3: The security token included in the request is invalid

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-sns, aws-sts

I'm attempting to publish a message to an SNS topic via a local Python program, working to learn Boto3.
I'm getting the error: `An error occurred (InvalidClientTokenId) when calling the GetSessionToken operation: The security token included in the request is invalid.`

This is occurring even after generating new access credentials and updating my AWS config file with the new access and secret keys. It seems I need a session token, but even the request to get a session token is met with the error that I need a session token. I'm just spinning in circles at this point, and can't figure out how to get this to move forward.

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem.
Windows Environment Variables were overriding my aws Config and Credential files.